# How to edit local group policy with PowerShell runs only one time

Tags: powershell

I'm searching this how to edit and modify a value, to set either `Enabled` or `Disabled` with PowerShell but only the first time user logs in for the first startup.

I googled this but most of the commands states in websites, are command not found on PowerShell, or they even do nothing. I mean they don't change the value.

In fact I'm trying to change the Network Level Authentication.